# Create connection in Airflow Docker using entrypoint.sh

Tags: bash, docker, docker-compose, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I am working on creating local dev environment for Airflow using Docker. I have setup most of the things but not able to create connection automatically in airflow.  I can bash into the docker container and run my command by following steps:

1. `docker exec -it jdf90dfusiodfsocontainerid /bin/sh`
2. `airflow connections add 'my_con_id'  --conn-uri 'SSH://myuser@255.255.255.255:22'`

I tried to automate it by adding a run command in Dockerfile as below:

`RUN ["/bin/bash", "-c", "airflow connections add 'my_con_id'  --conn-uri 'SSH://myuser@255.255.255.255:22'"]`

This throws error and that makes me think that this statement run before I made some necessary adjustment of variable in docker-compose and airflow.cfg files. So now my goal is to run the airflow connections command after all setup commands has run. I tried putting this command `airflow connections add 'my_con_id'  --conn-uri 'SSH://myuser@255.255.255.255:22'`in entrypoint.sh but it is not running. I also tried to echo some statements from entrypoint.sh but none of those statements are getting printed in my terminal. Am I doing something wrong here?

here is a entrypoint.sh that I am following: Any other way to create airflow connection in docker is also welcome.

https://github.com/aws/aws-mwaa-local-runner/blob/main/docker/script/entrypoint.sh